# How to use 2 power supplies in transistor key?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, raspberry-pi

I have 2 power supplies in my scheme, one is from Raspberry Pi GPIO and one is 9v battery. I need GPIO output to work like a button, e.g. when output from GPIO is 1, battery should power the scheme and when output 0, the scheme should not work. I've read that the transistor key is what I need in this situation, but I can't figure out how to connect all of it. There is 2 grounds, 1 from RPi and 1 from battery, and 2 +'s one from GPIO output and one from battery.

Can you show me the right way to do it? Or what should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple example of how to achieve this. Here V1 is your GPIO pin an V2 is your battery. R_load is whatever your trying to switch and R1 is a current limiting resistor and is optional. R2 limits current from pi and will need to be adjusted depeding on your load and R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5HUul.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>